# Unit test of the second method call

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, fluent-assertions

I have a unit test where I am using Moq and Fluent Assertions:

```
[Fact]
public void GetSymbols_ShouldSetSucceedToTrue_WhenSecondAttemptSucceed()
{
    string selectedFileName = "testFileName.txt";
    string[] expectedResult = new string[] { "testSymbol1", "testSymbol2" };
    Mock<IOpenFileDialogService> mockFileDialogService = new Mock<IOpenFileDialogService>();
    mockFileDialogService.SetupSequence(m => m.ShowDialog()).Returns(false).Returns(true);
    mockFileDialogService.Setup(m => m.FileName).Returns(selectedFileName);
    Mock<IFileService> mockFileService = new Mock<IFileService>();
    mockFileService.Setup(m => m.ReadAllLines(selectedFileName)).Returns(expectedResult);
    SymbolsProviderFromFile spff = new SymbolsProviderFromFile(mockFileDialogService.Object, mockFileService.Object);

    // Act
    spff.GetSymbols();
    IEnumerable<string> result = spff.GetSymbols();

    // Assert
    using (new AssertionScope())
    {
        result.Should().Equal(expectedResult);
        spff.Succeed.Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

I would like to check the second call of my method.
Unfortunately when I debug this code, the `spff.GetSymbols()` method is only called once and it is called on the `result.Should().Equals(expectedResult)` line when the result is checked. There is some kind of a lazy loading here - the method is only called when the result is needed.
Why is it not called immediately in the `spff.GetSymbols()` line? How can I change this behavior and how can I call testing method twice in unit test?

Comment: hi, just add  .ToList() to end of first call; spff.GetSymbols().ToList().

Comment: Exactly. I'm 100% confident that your method `GetSymbols` is called twice. But I suspect that your implementation uses LINQ, `yield` or something like that.

Comment: @DennisDoomen yes, implementation of the `GetSymbols()` method uses `yield`. So maybe here is the reason why it is not called immediately?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved thanks to @Dennis Doomen.

An issue about not executing method immediately was in the implementation of the `spff.GetSymbols()` method which uses `yield return` so it wasn't really related to unit testing.